# Simplifications assuming function is a probability distribution

Tags: simplifying-expressions, probability-or-statistics

Is it possible to define a generic probability distribution function (pdf) so Mathematica can use its properties to simplify expressions?

For example:

`Simplify[Integrate[f[x],{x,-Infinity,Infinity}]]`

How to tell to Mathematica that `f[x]` is a PDF so it can simplify (in this case) to 1?

This is easy for a PDF from a given distribution, but my question is about the case of a generic PDF `f[x]`

Answer (score 4):

`ProbabilityDistribution` does precisely that.

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ProbabilityDistribution.html

Comment: Yes, it's true that you can use something like `ProbabilityDistribution[f[y], {y, -Infinity, Infinity}]` for a generic `f[x]`, and it works. I didn't see that on the examples, so I assumed that was not possible.  Do you know if is it possible to assume further conditions, for example, that f[x] is a continuous distribution? So it can simplify even further (for example, `Simplify[  Integrate[f[y], {y, -Infinity, 10}] +    Integrate[f[y], {y, 10, Infinity}]]`)

Comment: Just define your f(x) to be continuous.

Answer (score 4):

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]
```

Use [`TagSet`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TagSet.html) or [`TagSetDelayed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TagSetDelayed.html) to associate the integral to the symbol `f`, e.g.,

```
f /: Integrate[f[x_], {x_, -Infinity, Infinity}] = 1;
```

Then

```
Integrate[f[y], {y, -Infinity, Infinity}]

(* 1 *)
```

**EDIT:**

Mathematica doesn't combine integrals unless explicitly told to do so. Define a rule

```
intRule = Integrate[expr_, {t_, a_, b_}] +
    Integrate[expr_, {t_, b_, c_}] :>
   Integrate[expr, {t, a, c}];
```

Applying the rule,

```
Integrate[f[y], {y, -Infinity, 10}] + 
  Integrate[f[y], {y, 10, Infinity}] /. intRule

(* 1 *)
```

Comment: It works for that integration, but not for other. For example, ```Simplify[
 Integrate[f[y], {y, -Infinity, 10}] + 
  Integrate[f[y], {y, 10, Infinity}]]``` does not simplify to 1.